# Why getters/setters are missing after stringifying and parsing back to an object?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

```js
var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        this._greeting = message;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Greeter.prototype, "greet", {
        get: function () {
            return "Hello, " + this._greeting;
        },
        set: function (message) {
            this._greeting = message;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    Greeter.prototype.toJSon = function () {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    };
    return Greeter;
}());
var greeter = new Greeter("world");
var JsonObject = greeter.toJSon();
alert(JsonObject);
// {"_greeting":"world1"} - this is good.

var newGreeter = JSON.parse(JsonObject);
var button = document.createElement('button');

button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function () {
    alert(newGreeter.greet);
    // undefined -- property is missing from object.
    alert(newGreeter._greeting);
    // works fine with "world"
};
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

In the above code, I created a `Greeter` object with a getter and a setter. It works fine when I create it.

But once I stringify it, parse it back to a new `Greeter` object, and try to read the getters/setters, it returns `undefined` for the `greet` property.

How can I parse a JSON object back to an object and have the getters/setters working?

Comment: This issue is unrelated to TypeScript

Comment: Just a little advice: if you're going to work with Javascript a lot, try not to think of "types" and "casting" in a traditional sense; there's really no such thing. If you want something to be of a certain type, you will have to create something new.

Answer (score 2):

When you serialize (stringify) an object, it will necessarily lose everything but its key-value pairs. Getters and setters (and other functions) cannot be serialized.

The best you can do is populate `greet` with a value, even if it won't have a setter/getter. If you want the `greet` property to be available in the stringified object, you'll have to call `defineProperty` on the instantiated object itself, not on the prototype, in order for `JSON.stringify(this)` to successfully call the getter:

```js
var Greeter = /** @class */ (function() {
  function Greeter(message) {
    this._greeting = message;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "greet", {
      get: function() {
        return "Hello, " + this._greeting;
      },
      set: function(message) {
        this._greeting = message;
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
  }
  Greeter.prototype.toJSon = function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
    return JSON.stringify(this);
  };
  return Greeter;
}());

var greeter = new Greeter("world");
var JsonObject = greeter.toJSon();

var newGreeter = JSON.parse(JsonObject);
var button = document.createElement('button');

button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function () {
    console.log(newGreeter.greet);
    console.log(newGreeter._greeting);
};
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method, that converts a pure JSON object (which can't contain methods) back to an object of your class:

```
function fromJSON(jsonString){
   var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
   var greeter = new Greeter();
   return Object.assign(greeter, jsonObj);
}
```

`Object.assign()` adds all properties of the second (third, ...) object to the first one, so your Greeter object now has the previous properties.